# What are the oldest Celtic and pre-Celtic settlements/oppida in France/Belgium?

Tags: celts, settlement

I am looking for a list of old Celtic and pre-Celtic settlements/[oppida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppidum) in France/Belgium and the period during which they were found. I found some information on Wikipedia on cities in France that existed during Roman times, but nothing about the period they were found (see [French Wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_noms_latins_des_villes_fran%C3%A7aises)), and also an interesting [Digital Atlas of the Roman Empire](http://dare.ht.lu.se/places/53.html) but again nothing about the time the towns were erected.
Could anyone give me a good reference that also provides periods when the settlements were found? The older they go back in time, the better.

Comment: Just for the record, we frown on reference requests and  on questions that generate "lists" - both types of questions make it very difficult to select an authoritative answer.  There is extensive discussion of this on  [meta.history.stackexchange.com].  Having said that, I personally think this question is well formed; the question is interesting and I can't imagine an edit that would bring it closer to our guidelines without undermining the question. Other opinions welcome, but I'd love to see someone answer this.

Comment: Might be able to narrow it by asking for the 'largest' or 'earliest' known of these settlements. Makes it a single solution, but usually still gets numerous responses.